# Doex xlwings handle arguments in the python call?

Tags: python, excel, xlwings, vba

```
Public Sub Run_Calibrate(sector As String)
Dim runString As String
Dim kwargs As String


kwargs = "{" & "'pd_grade_o':" & "[" & _
                   pd_array(0) & ", " & pd_array(1) & ", " & pd_array(2) & ", " & _
                   pd_array(3) & ", " & pd_array(4) & ", " & pd_array(5) & ", " & _
                   pd_array(6) & ", " & pd_array(7) & ", " & pd_array(8) & ", " & _
                   pd_array(9) & ", " & pd_array(10) & ", " & pd_array(11) & "], " & _
              "'ue_rate_6_o':" & "[" & _
                   ue_rate_6_o(0) & ", " & ue_rate_6_o(1) & ", " & ue_rate_6_o(2) & ", " & _
                   ue_rate_6_o(3) & ", " & ue_rate_6_o(4) & ", " & ue_rate_6_o(5) & ", " & _
                   ue_rate_6_o(6) & ", " & ue_rate_6_o(7) & ", " & ue_rate_6_o(8) & ", " & _
                   ue_rate_6_o(9) & ", " & ue_rate_6_o(10) & ", " & ue_rate_6_o(11) & "], " & _
              "'sbli_yoy_o':" & "[" & _
                   sbli_yoy_o(0) & ", " & sbli_yoy_o(1) & ", " & sbli_yoy_o(2) & ", " & _
                   sbli_yoy_o(3) & ", " & sbli_yoy_o(4) & ", " & sbli_yoy_o(5) & ", " & _
                   sbli_yoy_o(6) & ", " & sbli_yoy_o(7) & ", " & sbli_yoy_o(8) & ", " & _
                   sbli_yoy_o(9) & ", " & sbli_yoy_o(10) & ", " & sbli_yoy_o(11) & "], " & _
              "'nfpr_6_o':" & "[" & _
                   nfpr_6_o(0) & ", " & nfpr_6_o(1) & ", " & nfpr_6_o(2) & ", " & _
                   nfpr_6_o(3) & ", " & nfpr_6_o(4) & ", " & nfpr_6_o(5) & ", " & _
                   nfpr_6_o(6) & ", " & nfpr_6_o(7) & ", " & nfpr_6_o(8) & ", " & _
                   nfpr_6_o(9) & ", " & nfpr_6_o(10) & ", " & nfpr_6_o(11) & "], "

kwargs = kwargs & _
         "'60':" & "[" & _
         w_60(0) & ", " & w_60(1) & ", " & w_60(2) & "], " & _
         "'90':" & "[" & _
         w_90(0) & ", " & w_90(1) & ", " & w_90(2) & "], " & _
         "'120':" & "[" & _
         w_120(0) & ", " & w_120(1) & ", " & w_120(2) & "], " & _
         "'150':" & "[" & _
         w_150(0) & ", " & w_150(1) & ", " & w_150(2) & "], " & _
         "'180':" & "[" & _
         w_180(0) & ", " & w_180(1) & ", " & w_180(2) & "]}"

Debug.Print kwargs
runString = Chr(34) & "import DQforecast; DQforecast.calibrate('" & sector & "', " & kwargs & ")" & Chr(34)
Debug.Print runString


RunPython (runString)

End Sub
```

Can xlwings handle the kwargs being passed in method call?  I get a

```
File "<string>", line 1 
invalid syntax
```

I've configured my xlwings settings so that the PYTHON_WIN and PYTHON_PATH are correct, and i've succesfully run functions with no parameters from xlwings.

Comment: What does your Python code look like? Consider pasting it in a github gist. While xlwings hasn't been really designed for this use case, simple things should be possible. And yours look like a simple thing...

Answer (score 0):

As per the [docs](http://docs.xlwings.org/vba.html#call-python-with-runpython), yes it does.

The problem with your code is reflected in the syntax highlighting itself. You are not closing the string before the closing parenthesis of `RunPython` call. The following code should work:

```
Sub test()
RunPython("import DQforecast; DQforecast.calibrate('OP Dealer')")
end Sub
```

Comment: My apologies, i wrote that up quickly and forgot the " , but the real error is not that.  I posted the full code up above... I'm trying to pass a couple dictionaries through the calibrate method.  Heres output of the runString: `"import DQforecast; DQforecast.calibrate('OP Dealer', {'pd_grade_o':[, , , , , , , , , , , ], 'ue_rate_6_o':[, , , , , , , , , , , ], 'sbli_yoy_o':[, , , , , , , , , , , ], 'nfpr_6_o':[, , , , , , , , , , , ], '60':[, , ], '90':[, , ], '120':[, , ], '150':[, , ], '180':[, , ]})"`

Comment: And i've gone throug the docs, there is not a single example or mention of parameters being passed through a method call in the RunPython function